# How I can use a css and javascript menu in my asp.net application?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, css

hi i want test a menu in my asp.net application but i get a javascript error.

here my aspx:

```
<nav id="cbp-hrmenu" class="cbp-hrmenu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Products</a>
            <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
                    <div>
                        <h4>Learning & Games</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Catch the Bullet</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Snoopydoo</a></li>
                            <!-- ... -->
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h4>Utilities</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Gadget Finder</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Green Tree Express</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Green Tree Pro</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Wobbler 3.0</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Coolkid</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <!-- ... -->
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
            </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
        </li>
        <li><!-- ... --></li>
        <li><!-- ... --></li>
        <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here the javascript:

```
var cbpHorizontalMenu = (function() {

    var $listItems = $( '#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li' ), //<--error $listItems is undefine
        $menuItems = $listItems.children( 'a' ),
        $body = $( 'body' ),
        current = -1;

    function init() {
        $menuItems.on( 'click', open );
        $listItems.on( 'click', function( event ) { event.stopPropagation(); } );
    }

    function open( event ) {

        if( current !== -1 ) {
            $listItems.eq( current ).removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
        }

        var $item = $( event.currentTarget ).parent( 'li' ),
            idx = $item.index();

        if( current === idx ) {
            $item.removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
            current = -1;
        }
        else {
            $item.addClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
            current = idx;
            $body.off( 'click' ).on( 'click', close );
        }

        return false;

    }

    function close( event ) {
        $listItems.eq( current ).removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
        current = -1;
    }

    return { init : init };

})();
```

What I must do  :(

Comment: If you are using jQuery - do not use the $ in your variable names.

Comment: $( '#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li' ) is jQuery syntax, so it appears that you are using jQuery or some other library that uses a similar syntax.  You are also using jQuery functions like on() and removeClass() so I'm pretty sure it's jQuery.

Comment: I'm guessing $ is undefined might be your error? Try loading jQuery. Or tell us what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added CSS to your ASP.NET application?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" runat="server" media="screen" href="~/css/styles.css" />
```

to create integration with Javascript file and ASP.NET file, you can just add `*.js` to your `<head>` tags, by do this:

```
<head runat="server">
<script src="FileName.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

I also noticed that you're using jQuery library, you might didn't include it. Put it also in your `<head>` tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```